# PHP Redirect using custom variables from HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect, get

Not 100% sure if there's already an answer for this but I'm struggling to find anything. I want to take a string from a html  and use it to redirect a user to a subdomain. For example if the user enters "abc123" into the form, they will be redirected to abc123.awebsite.com. It seems like it should be pretty simple but I can't quite work it out. My code so far is as follows:

HTML:

```
<form action="redirect.php" method="get">
<span>
Reference:
<input type="text" name="reference">
</span>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<form>
```

PHP:

```
$redirectlocation = ["reference"] + ".awebsite.com"

function redirect($url, $statusCode = 303)
{
   header('Location: redirectlocation ' . $url, true, $statusCode);
   die();
}
```

Apologies for the awful explanation

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This, look [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-303-redirect/) to read more.

A proper `303 redirect` sends a `HTTP/1.1 303 See Other` header, then the url Location.

```
function redirect($url, $statusCode = 303)
{
   header("HTTP/1.1 " . $statusCode . " See Other");
   header("Location: " . $url);
   die();
}
```

To get the value from the form, you used the method `GET` in your form, so you can use the `$_GET[key]` array passed to the script from your form, the keys of this array are the `name=""` attributes of your html form inputs.

```
 $redirectlocation = "http://" . $_GET["reference"] . ".awebsite.com";
redirect($redirectlocation);
```

Comment: For some reason 
`$redirectlocation = $_GET["reference"] + ".awebsite.com";
Redirect($redirectlocation);` returns 0 regardless of what is entered. 

This however does work but doesn't allow for the redirect to be changed by the form input:
`Redirect('http://example.com/'); `

Comment: do you need to add `http://` to `$redirectlocation = $_GET["reference"] + ".awebsite.com";` like `$redirectlocation = "http://" + $_GET["reference"] + ".awebsite.com";`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I've just tried that and still seem to be having trouble. I've tried using `<?php echo $redirectlocation; ?>` to check that it's not something else messing it up but that returns a 0 too.

Comment: `$redirectlocation = $_GET["reference"];` does redirect so it seems to be a problem creating the string?

Comment: This worked although some of it is redundant:
`$reference = $_GET["reference"];
$http = "http://";
$domain = ".awebsite.com";

$redirectlocation = $http . $reference . $domain;
Redirect($redirectlocation);`

Comment: Sorry, My fault I forgot to change that `+` sign in the string my updated post will work. `+` is the concatenation operator in javascript and `.` is PHP, I often get them confused.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked:

**HTML**

```
<form action="redirect2.php" method="get">
<span>
Reference:
<input type="text" name="reference">
</span>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
function redirect($url, $statusCode = 303)
{
   header("HTTP/1.1 " . $statusCode . " See Other");
   header('Location: ' . $url, true, $statusCode);
   die();
}
$reference = $_GET["reference"];
$http = "http://";
$domain = ".awebsite.com";

$redirectlocation = $http . $reference . $domain;
Redirect($redirectlocation);
```